# ClassNotFoundException in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have received an IntelliJ project from someone else, but it won't run even the simplest classes for me.

As a quick example, the following class will throw a `ClassNotFoundException` without compiler errors:

```
package myPackage;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        System.out.println("Soon our GUI will start from here!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This will throw the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myPackage.Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The file structure is as follows:
`<git root>`/`src`/`myPackage`/`Main.java`

I have set the 'src' folder as the 'source folder'. My application has no compiler errors. 
I have invalidated the caches several times, but with no effect whatsoever. 
In my module settings my module dependencies contain `<Module source>` and jdk 1.8.

I can't seem to find the answer around here (google) anywhere, and to me it seems like this error has to do with the way IntelliJ handles the project. When I first pulled the project, the `src` folder had NOT been set to be the source folder, which probably means I may be missing out on other settings as well.

Comment: Did the git repo contain an intellij project? If so that is likely the problem. Typically when you manage a project, 90% of the project files are not relevant to the code, and may be machine/os specific. Its better to gitignore the project files and build a new project on each developer machine. I'd suggest deleting the project (not the code) and creating a new one. Then gitignore all the intellij files to avoid this in the future

Comment: @ZackNewsham What do you mean by "project"? The .idea folder?

Comment: @yts exactly, its the same for all IDE's netbeans is an nbproject though.

Comment: I meant the .idea folder, yes. This issue has been resolved by replacing the project files, as Zack suggested. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Zack Newsham's suggestion helped me. Here is what I did:

1. Deleted .iml file
2. File > New > Project, specified the existing folder with code
3. completed project setup (Manifest, artifacts).

Now the project runs.

Of course there may be other reasons for `ClassNotFound`. However when everything seems ok or if the error comes up after it worked before, try these simple steps.

Comment: While you're at it, you should add IntelliJ's project files to your project's .gitignore. See https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore